# Canary deployments for Lambda with CodeDeploy and CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, canary-deployment

I can't seem to set up a pipeline that uses CodeDeploy for a lambda function. I have tried:

1. Generating the appspec.yml file as part of a CodeBuild action. In this case CodePipeline zips the file, and CodeDeploy says it can't find the appspec file.
2. Generating the appspec.yml file manually (Lambda invocation). In this case CodeDeploy gives the error "The deployment specifies that the revision is a null file, but the revision provided is a zip file." (It is definitely not a zip file)

Has anyone succeeded in doing this?

Note: I know SAM apparently does this. But it would be difficult to introduce new tooling at this point...

Comment: Have you verified that the 'CodePipeline zip' has the file?

Comment: Yes the zip has the appspec file. I think the problem is that CodeDeploy for Lambda specifically wants a json or yaml file, and does not support a zip bundle. So far all my research points to this just being impossible

Comment: Hey @chickenpie, have you managed to figure out how to do deployments via aws cli?

Comment: @davids No, not using the cli. I ended up using lambda actions in CodePipeline to do the 3 steps I needed: Publish the new lambda version from latest, generate the appspec file with the old and new version, and call CodeDeploy to do the canary deployment.

Comment: @chickenpie I was wondering whether the appspec file is needed for Lambda deployments. In the docs, it says that the revision can be specified as a string parameter: --revision '{"revisionType": "String", "string": {"content":"revision-as-string"}}'. It's also true that the appspec files contains information about hooks, for example, but those details would be already available in the DeploymentGroup

Comment: I was not using the cli so I don't really know about its parameters. Maybe you dont need an appspec file with the cli.